# Standardize formatting in excel

Tags: excel

[Attachment](http://C:%5CUsers%5Cpc102028%5CDesktop)
How can excel remember my standardize formatting, Like

Standard font 
Color
Boarding
etc.

Is there any command through which excel remember all this. And i can apply this formatting to all annexures by single click.

Please Find attachment for more clarification

Comment: your attachment links to a file on your local computer, not to something on the internet...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible..
you just need to create an addin into excel and then import that addin on Quick Access Toolbar.
Refer my image. Also i don't know what formatting you want so help me with sample excel so that i can help you...

[image]